# How to make the chevron in resource manager of vscode not show?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to make the icon chevron no show when i using materialicons instead the default icons.
[image]

I want to make the chevron no show.

[image]

Comment: Can you share an image with how actually it should look like?

Comment: The folder icons are aligned with the file icons. Folder `components` and file `designer.vue` are both direct children of `dashboard`, and they are aligned. Folder `router` and file `index.js` are not on the same level, so they are misaligned.

Comment: I edit the question,please have a look.@Marcel  @GSerg

Comment: I still don't see any alignment differences. The items on the same level are aligned in both cases, the items on different levels are not. If you in fact are not concerned with alignment, and simply want to get rid of the chevron icon while keeping all other indentations in place, please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: there is an extension to inject custom CSS in VSC. Find the full class specification of the chevron `monaco-tl-twistie collapsible codicon codicon-tree-item-expanded` and `monaco-tl-twistie codicon codicon-tree-item-expanded collapsible collapsed` and set its display to none, and don't forget to remove the content of the `:before` specifier, You will be left with 16px padding because that is hard coded in the tag, maybe an `padding-left:0 !important` will do the trick

Comment: Could you please tell me what the extension is? @rioV8